# Move from Azure Table Storage to other database

Tags: sql-server, azure, nosql, azure-table-storage

I have been asked to move an Azure Table Storage service from the Microsoft Dublin Data Centre to a data centre in the UK (any secure data centre so long as it is UK based).  My problem is that Azure table storage is only supported in Microsoft data centres (Dublin and Amsterdam in Europe).

There are about 50 tables plus queues and blobs.  The data requirements are for highly scalable storage.  I do not want to re-write the storage into SQL Server because this will require schema management and direct management of the indexes for performance.  I would prefer a performant nosql database that operates to the standards of Azure table storage.

Does anyone have any experience in this area?

Answer (score 1):

As far as migrating your data, there's no automated way to do it. Check out the [AzCopy](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2012/12/03/azcopy-uploading-downloading-files-for-windows-azure-blobs.aspx) utility for blobs.

As far as which database to choose, that's really going to be app-dependent. You'll need to think about search, storage, indexing, map/reduce/aggregation, etc. Then there's document, column, graph, key/value, sql - you may choose one or a combination.

Just remember that Table Storage is storage-as-a-service, with triple-replicated storage providing durability, and upwards of 2000 tps per partition, 20K tps per storage account. You'll need to build this out yourself, whatever you choose (maybe [Redis](http://redis.io/)?).

Anyway: This is pretty wide-open as far as solving your architecture. But hopefully I gave you something to think about.

One more thing: You should really look into the reasons for moving your data. Many people talk about data sovereignty, but sometimes it turns out that the data location doesn't violate any local data laws (or that some data can actually remain where it is, with only specific data needing to be hosted within a country's boundaries).